# HTTPS connection to API not working Express/Node/Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS instance running and created a certificate using certbot:
I can go with the browser to https://www.tichutimo.ch/ and it shows the default page.
There is a route configured http://www.tichutimo.ch:5000/api/users/test which just responds with some text. With http this works fine.
But when I try https://www.tichutimo.ch:5000/api/users/test I get `"SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"` in firefox.

Now I am not even sure where to look for a solution: In express? In nginx?
I don't see anything in my express logs..

With curl i get `curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use nginx set up as a reverse proxy.  In that setup, it is supposed to accept incoming https connections (on the default port 443) and pass them along to your nodejs server via http://localhost:5000 in your case. This is a good high-performance setup: nginx handles the https heavy lifting, and your nodejs program can be dedicated to your application.

So, your https URL isn't right. Take out the port 5000 reference. Like this.   https://www.tichutimo.ch/api/users/test

But, when I tried it on your site I got nginx's 404 page.  Your front door page shows nginx's default page. So, it seems likely your /etc/nginx.conf isn't set up correctly to do the reverse proxy work.

The 'toobz have plenty of good tutorials on that, and explaining it is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Please ask another question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to @o-jones comment.

1. I had to remove the port from the request
2. I had to add the line with proxy_pass as seen below

   ```
   location / {
          proxy_pass       http://localhost:5000;
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm delighted it was that simple. I use nginx for websockets and it's a lot more complicated.